# Vue get props into component in typescript setup unused

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-props

I am trying to bring my props into my component.
Found this documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props which is referenced close to everywhere.
Obviously I should put my type into the defineProps function.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  foo: { type: String, required: true },
  bar: Number
})

props.foo // string
props.bar // number | undefined - they are not usable in the template if I just define the const...
</script>
```

So I tried to put them to my component. But to do so I need to do sth within the setup.

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    message: String
  },
  setup(props) {
    props.message // <-- type: string
  }
})
```

```js
<template>
    <CNavItem :href="props.href">
    <CIcon customClassName="nav-icon" :icon="icon" />{{label}}</CNavItem>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, defineProps } from "vue";
import { CNavItem } from '@coreui/vue';
import { CIcon } from '@coreui/icons-vue';

interface Props {
    label: string;
    href: string;
    icon: any[];
}

const props = defineProps<Props>();
export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        CNavItem,
        CIcon
    },
    setup(props) {
        // I need to do sth with props here I guess, but I do not know how to get it to my template.
        // If I don't the compiler will complain...
    }
});
</script>
```

I think I have a missig link somewhere here. So how would I get my content of `const props` into my template?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue here. What do you mean by `they are not usable in the template if I just define the const`? The props defined in a `<script setup>` with `defineProps()` are directly accessible in the template. e.g., given `defineProps<{ msg:string }>()`, your template could have `<h2>{{ msg }}</h2>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defineProps` can only be used inside `<script setup>` (`ts` or `js`).
In the example you posted, you're trying to use it inside a `<script>` tag's root (does not have the `setup` attribute!), where it won't work.

---

To clarify:

- **`<script setup lang="ts">` syntax:**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  foo: Number
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>{{ foo }}</div>
</template>
```

- **`<script lang="ts">` syntax:**

```html
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    foo: Number
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>{{ foo }}</div>
</template>
```

---

See them working [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have mixed the two ways.

Have you tried to do as below?

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  // type inference enabled
  props: {
    label: String,
    href: String,
    icon: any[]
  },
  setup(props) {
    props.label // ...
    // ...
  }
})
```

See [the link](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#general-usage-notes).